# Modify Pandas dataFrame column values based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to modify only the values that are greater than 750 on a column of a pandas dataframe

```
datf.iloc[:,index][datf.iloc[:,index] > 750] = datf.iloc[:,index][datf.iloc[:,index] > 750]/10.7639
```

I think that the syntax is fine but i get a Pandas warning so i don't know if its correct this way:

```
<ipython-input-24-72eef50951a4>:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

What is the correct way to do this without getting this warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply method to make your modification to your column using your custom function.
N.B you can also use the applymap for multiple columns

```
def my_func(x):
    if x > 750:
        x= #do your modification
    else:
       x
    return x

new_dta= datf['col_name'].apply(my_func)
```